# Mathematicians conceived of black holes long before astronomers actually found any?How?

Tags: physics

I read this statement in Lockhart's - "A Mathematician's Lament". But how could mathematicians  figure out something like black holes even before astronomers noticing any of them?

Comment: General relativity!

Comment: Any more details would be wonderful!!

Comment: One issue is that the escape velocity can be greater than the speed of light. What happens then?

Comment: Google the keywords "Schwarzschild solution". And it is in fact in the very FIRST place black hole exists in math (some object has a smaller radius than its Schwarzschild radius), then astronomers went on to design methods to detect them (like exploiting gravity lens effect).

Comment: A word of caution about the looseness of that claim: Most everyone involved in developing the theory of black holes would be described primarily as a theoretical physicist/astrophysicist, *not* a mathematician. You could ask how does *any* theorist make predictions prior to having observations, but that's just what a *pre*diction is, and it's exactly what theoretical scientists do all day long.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without going into the details (which I'm not intimately familiar with), it was possible because physicists and mathematicians (such as Lorentz, Einstein and Minkowski) had developed a good mathematical model of gravitation.  Using this model - which is a system of partial differential equations - physicists and mathematicians were able to predict that gravitational *singularities* should form under certain conditions.  As a very (very) simplified example of what I mean, suppose that we have modeled some quantity with the simple ODE

$$
\dot{x}=x^2,\quad x(0)=1
$$  The solution to this equation is the function

$$
x(t)=\frac{1}{1-t}
$$

This function exhibits *finite time blow-up*, since when $t=1$, we have a singularity - a place where $x(t)$ becomes infinite.  If the ODE models our system accurately, we should be able to observe this blow-up with measurements.  The same is true of gravitational singularities - the model predicts a blow-up, so astronomers went looking for (and found) those singularities.

Comment: Are mathematical rules followed in case of a "blow-up"? Can mathematicians look beyond?

Comment: @eminemence There are ways of dealing with singularities, yes.  It's delicate, of course, but possible.

Comment: So mathematicians predict based on models. Chances are that things may not turn out as predicted. Black hole was the case where things were found as predicted.

Comment: @eminemence Correct - if we weren't able to find black holes, we would probably try to fix the model.  A model is only good if the data supports it!